# Get the shell to recognize shortcuts

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

`C:\Program Files (x86)\` is dreadful, so I have a directory `C:\Users\Braden\Programs\bin` that is in the `%PATH%` environment variable. This directory is conceptually equivalent to `/usr/local/bin` on a *NIX system. I.e. A single place where I can throw executables to where I can execute them by just typing their names (whether that's in a `cmd.exe` shell or a `Run...` dialog.). It works fine for straight `PE*` format executables and batch scripts, but strangely *not* for shortcuts.

Take VLC, for example. I have a shortcut to VLC named `vlc.lnk`, which as I understand, is supposed to be the equivalent of a `hard link`. I have to type in `vlc.lnk`, not `vlc`, to get it to execute the program. I find this ridiculous.

Is there some way I can make the commandline treat a `.lnk` the same way as a `.bat` or `.exe`, where I can just type in the filename without the extension? Preferably without installing an external program.

While on the subject, is it possible to do the same with any arbitrary file, like, say, a `.bash` or `.sh` file? I could totally get behind a wrapper script written in bash.

Comment: A .lnk file contains the list of arguments that will be passed onto the .exe program.  If you don't like how that works, don't use a .lnk file.  You could, for instance, use a .bat file.  Try: `echo "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 >> %USERPROFILE%\Programs\Bin\vlc.bat` (and then run "vlc filename")

Comment: Would you be happier specifying the data file directly, and having VLC run automatically based on file association, instead of trying to run VLC directly and then specifying what data file it should use?

Comment: @Ramhound NB: I deleted the comment you're referring to, which means the context is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`ECHO %PATHEXT%
SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.LNK`